# No back button for Handheld.PlayFullScreenMovie method

Tags: unity-game-engine, video, handheld

I am trying play a fullscreen video in my app (iOS&Android). When users press on video I use the
Handheld.PlayFullScreenMovie method and it displays the videos perfectly. BUT, there is no back button in the player. The only way to exit player and switch back to the scene is to wait untill the video ends. How can I fix this problem? It is so obvious that users may need the back button and idk why Unity does not added it

Comment: Could you show your code? In particular which option do you pass in for `controlMode`? Also note `On iOS, Handheld.PlayFullScreenMovie internally uses MPMoviePlayerController object to play movies. Therefore, you should expect the same behavior` maybe it simply doesn't provide a back button? In that case you might want to try [`FullScreenMovieControlMode.CancelOnInput`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/FullScreenMovieControlMode.CancelOnInput.html)